# List index out of range preventing 404 error?

Tags: python, server

I'm trying to complete this lab but cannot seem to get it to work correctly. When I try to get a file not present of the server, I am given

> This page isn’t working
>   127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
>   ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

The response I'd like to get is along the lines of

> 404 File not found

When I try to load a file not present, the compiler says for line 16:

> filename = message.split()[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

The code compiles and I am able to open my Hello World file, but I am just not able to get this 404 error. I was given a skeleton code, so there are some things that I cannot change without deviating from course material.

```
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
#Prepare a server socket
serverPort = 7000
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(5)

while True:
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    #Fill in start #Fill in end
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print (message)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        #Fill in start
        connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.x 200 OK\n'.encode())

        #Fill in end
        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
        print ('File Recieved')

    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send('\n404 File Not Found\n'.encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
        #Close client socket

serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()
```

The skeleton code appears to be Python 2, and I'm using Python 3. I've made some minor syntax adjustments to adjust.

Removing print(message) yields "File Recieved" in the compiler, but still no 404 error in the browser. I'm at loss after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle an `IndexError` in `message.split()[1]` is to handle and `IndexError` in `message.split()[1]` ;)

```
try:
    filename = message.split()[1]
except IndexError:
    send_404_response()
    continue
```

Comment: Another way is to check what is in `message` beforehand, but I cannot put that in answer because it is not clear what the request is supposed to look like, i.e. why there is `message.split()[1]` and then the weird `open(filename[1:])`.

Comment: Tried it. f = open(filename[1:])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'favicon.ico'

Comment: The message.split and open filename are all part of this skeleton code supplied by the textbook company.

Comment: I believe it is easy to understand how to handle the next error using the same approach I used for the previous error you had